# How to storage data from a html popup?

Tags: html, json, storage

I created a pop up with html with a list of answer. I need to store the answer selected by the user and then display the result in a dynamic infographic. What's the best way to storage the answer and display them in a dynamic infographic? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to get the value from the popup by JavaScript and store it into a variable